# Creating a login system in C#. .mdf database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008

So I've created a `.mdf` database in VS2010 following this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INrcHZBhB20

What I failed to realize is he is using an `.sdf` database. I don't want to use `.sdf` so how could I continue with my current database? I know this is a bit much but I am completely clueless and I don't want to use `.sdf` because VS2010 doesn't let me create one (I get an error).

If you need more info, let me know. I just want to make it where you can create and sign in to accounts using the database.

Comment: Do you have SQL express loaded on your machine?

Comment: Yes, SQL Express 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter SQL Server Express Management Studio and recreate your schema there. SQL Server Express creates `.mdf` databases.

Microsoft has a good tutorial here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186312(v=sql.105).aspx

You can most likely export your scripts for your database creation from visual studio and run them right in SQL Server Management Studio